# Aurelia - If params in Promise.all

Tags: javascript, json, api, aurelia

I am trying to work out a search page where a number of search types can be filled in.   Then a WebApi call is made if the search type is filled in and passed as a parameter to activate().

It seems inefficient to call the api if I know that the param is null/undefined, but I am not sure how to do something like this:

```
if (params.myparam === undefined)
   { don't include it in the promise }
else 
   { include in the promise }
```

Below is the code I have so far....

It all works properly as is but I end up passing "undefined" as the search parameter.  That doesn't work for me because there is actually a piece of art named "The Die Maker from the series Eight Sheets from an **Undefined** Novel" which in this case should not show up.  And "undefined" needs to be a valid search term.

```
    activate(params) {

    if(params.exhibitionID != null)
    {
        return this.apiData.getByExhibitionId(params.exhibitionID).then(exhibitions => { this.exhibitions = exhibitions.objects; if(exhibitions.objects.length > 0){ this.showExhibitions = "display"; this.exhibitionsCount = exhibitions.objects.length; this.exhibitionTitle = exhibitions.exhibitionTitle; } });
    }
    else
    {
        return Promise.all([
            this.apiData.getBySearchDated(params.searchDated).then(dateds => { this.dateds = dateds; if(dateds.length > 0){ this.showDateds = "display"; this.datedsCount = dateds.length; } }),
            this.apiData.getBySearchCreditline(params.searchCreditline).then(creditlines => { this.creditlines = creditlines; if(creditlines.length > 0){ this.showCreditlines = "display"; this.creditlinesCount = creditlines.length; } }),
            this.apiData.getBySearchNumber(params.searchNumber).then(numbers => { this.numbers = numbers; if(numbers.length > 0){ this.showNumbers = "display"; this.numbersCount = numbers.length; } }),
            this.apiData.getBySearchTitle(params.searchTitle).then(titles => { this.titles = titles; if(titles.length > 0){ this.showTitles = "display"; this.titlesCount = titles.length; } }),
            this.apiData.getBySearchCreator(params.searchCreator).then(creators => { this.creators = creators; if(creators.length > 0){ this.showCreators = "display"; this.creatorsCount = creators.length; } })
        ]);
    }
}
```

Here is what one of the api calls looks like.  I put in a hack that returns empty json, but it just seems right not to make the call in the first place if I know there are no results.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

API call:

```
getBySearchTitle(searchTitle) {

    // the hack
    // if(searchTitle == undefined){ searchTitle = token;}

    return this.http.fetch(baseUrl + "/objects/" + token + "&search=" + searchTitle + "&searchtype=title")
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(response => {

              if(response.length > 1000)
              {
                  alert("Your search returns too many results (maximum 1000).  Please refine your search and try again.");
                  this.router.navigateBack();
              }
              else{
                  return response.objects;
              }

          });
}
```

Comment: Could it be as simple as `!params.searchDated || this.apiData.getBySearchDated(params.searchDated)`? That checks if the parameter is `falsy` (`undefined == falsy`) and doesn't trigger the function if it is `undefined`.

Comment: You could also try to find out if the term is a `string`. Because `typeof undefined == object && typeof 'undefined' == string`, you wouldn't need to search for objects.

Comment: This worked btw.  Thank you VERY much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could check if the parameter exists before constructing the `Promise`. Your activate method would look something like this:

```
activate(params) {

    if(params.exhibitionID != null)
    {
        return this.apiData.getByExhibitionId(params.exhibitionID).then(exhibitions => { this.exhibitions = exhibitions.objects; if(exhibitions.objects.length > 0){ this.showExhibitions = "display"; this.exhibitionsCount = exhibitions.objects.length; this.exhibitionTitle = exhibitions.exhibitionTitle; } });
    }
    else
    {
        return Promise.all([
            !params.searchDated || this.apiData.getBySearchDated(params.searchDated).then(dateds => { this.dateds = dateds; if(dateds.length > 0){ this.showDateds = "display"; this.datedsCount = dateds.length; } }),
            !params.searchCreditline || this.apiData.getBySearchCreditline(params.searchCreditline).then(creditlines => { this.creditlines = creditlines; if(creditlines.length > 0){ this.showCreditlines = "display"; this.creditlinesCount = creditlines.length; } }),
            !params.searchNumber || this.apiData.getBySearchNumber(params.searchNumber).then(numbers => { this.numbers = numbers; if(numbers.length > 0){ this.showNumbers = "display"; this.numbersCount = numbers.length; } }),
            !params.searchTitle || this.apiData.getBySearchTitle(params.searchTitle).then(titles => { this.titles = titles; if(titles.length > 0){ this.showTitles = "display"; this.titlesCount = titles.length; } }),
            !params.searchCreator || this.apiData.getBySearchCreator(params.searchCreator).then(creators => { this.creators = creators; if(creators.length > 0){ this.showCreators = "display"; this.creatorsCount = creators.length; } })
        ]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting.  I don't have any errors, but I also don't have any results.  Still testing.  Please let me know if you have any thoughts on it.  Thanks!

Comment: Can you amend your answer to include the following and I'll mark it as correct.  I got it working through a combo of your code and teh comments above.  trick is to do something like this.....return Promise.all([
                !params.searchDated || this.apiData.getBySearchDated(params.searchDated).then(dateds => { this.dateds = dateds; if(dateds.length > 0){ this.showDateds = "display"; this.datedsCount = dateds.length; } }),  etc....

Comment: To tell you the truth, I expected your way to work.  It makes sense to me.

Comment: I think if you used that method and removed the function completely, it would've worked. I just thought I needed that function, but promises don't execute like that :(.

Comment: I actually thought this would not work because of the statement **inside** of the array. Funny world we live in.